# Cannot `yarn build` a project in a server

Tags: reactjs, npm, server

I just bought a fresh new `ecs.n4.small` server in Hongkong with `1 vCPU 2 GiB`.

In the server, I git cloned a React project which can be built well locally, then I did `yarn` and `yarn build`. After 3 minutes, it returned:

```
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8096 build
Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.

Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
```

In `/var/log/syslog`, I found:

```
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.316865] [25517]     0 25517   193946     6641     130      76        0             0 node
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.316867] [25538]     0 25538     1126       18       7       3        0             0 sh
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.316869] [25539]     0 25539   113703     1697      63      27        0             0 node
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.316871] [25546]     0 25546   629715   439566    6497    6041        0             0 node
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.316873] Out of memory: Kill process 25546 (node) score 856 or sacrifice child
May  1 08:34:45 AliYun kernel: [46379.317613] Killed process 25546 (node) total-vm:2518860kB, anon-rss:1757868kB, file-rss:396kB
May  1 08:35:01 AliYun CRON[25570]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Does anyone know what I should change to enable `yarn build` work in a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--max_old_space_size=8096` on your build script sets node's max ram to 8 gig but your server only has 2 gig. When node starts taking too much ram the system is killing it for being greedy.

Try removing the flag or buying a container with more ram. :)

Comment: OK... removing `--max_old_space_size:8096` did work; it took 3 minutes to build.